# Can not create new activity in specific project but the other projects working good

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, manjaro

### **Can not create a new activity in a specific project but the other projects working good**

Can not create a new activity in a specific project, but the other projects working well. When I select new activity the android studio just syncs the project without creating the activity, same with fragments. I am using Manjaro not windows.

I tried to clear the cache and restart the android studio but still the same.
By the way, the project was fine before, I did not change anything in it.

Comment: This may help: close android studio —> delete .gradle [C:\Users\username\.gradle] and .idea folders —> re-open project using android studio

Comment: The problem was in the string file  , when i removed some strings from the default string files that was not in the other string files , it is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for so long , finally i found the problem , the default string file had a strings that is not in the other strings files